# ERROR HTTP Status 405 ? Method Not Allowed when using GCP load balancer

Tags: spring, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, spring-security, load-balancing

I have an aplication made in spring boot, it recovers data from a remote PostgreSQL database. It works well locally (from local app to local db), from local host to remote db and with all resources on GCP cloud (vm with tomcat server that host the aplication and with a cloud SQL for PostgreSQL database). The last part of my PoC is to host my aplication in my instance group with a load balancer attached. When i reach my load balancer i can see my welcome page where i use spring security to login (revovers the credentials from the same postgreSQL database), but it isnt work and i recieve the next error:

[LB error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdaL7.png)

And when I check my catalina.out log, it shows me the next error:

```
11:34 ERROR 893 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Cannot forward to error page for request [/login] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
11:35  WARN 893 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

Im going to share my LB terraform code if helps, ´the lb part is seem to be the problem in my PoC.

```
provider "google-beta" {
  project     = var.project
  region      = "us-central1"
  credentials = "C:/Users/jperezgarcia/Desktop/Terraform/GCP/credentials/mario.json"
}

resource "google_compute_region_ssl_certificate" "ssl-crt" {
  provider    = google-beta
  project     = var.project
  name_prefix = "my-certificate-"
  region      = var.lb_region
  private_key = file("lb_http/certificate/privateKey.key")
  certificate = file("lb_http/certificate/certificate.crt")

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTP" {
  provider              = google-beta
  project               = var.project
  name                  = var.lb_front_name
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
  port_range            = var.lb_front_port_range
  target                = google_compute_region_target_http_proxy.lb-proxy-http.self_link
  region                = var.lb_region
  network               = var.lb_network
  subnetwork            = var.lb_subnetwork
  # ip_address            = "10.10.20.5"
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTPS" {
  provider              = google-beta
  project               = var.project
  name                  = "lb-https-front"
  port_range            = "443"
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
  # ip_address            = "10.10.20.5"
  target     = google_compute_region_target_https_proxy.lb-proxy-https.self_link
  region     = var.lb_region
  network    = var.lb_network
  subnetwork = var.lb_subnetwork
}


resource "google_compute_region_target_http_proxy" "lb-proxy-http" {
  provider = google-beta
  name     = var.lb_proxy_name
  region   = var.lb_region
  project  = var.project
  url_map  = google_compute_region_url_map.lb_url_map.self_link
}

resource "google_compute_region_target_https_proxy" "lb-proxy-https" {
  provider         = google-beta
  name             = "test-proxy"
  region           = var.lb_region
  project          = var.project
  url_map          = google_compute_region_url_map.lb_url_map.self_link
  ssl_certificates = [google_compute_region_ssl_certificate.ssl-crt.id]
}


resource "google_compute_region_url_map" "lb_url_map" {
  provider        = google-beta
  project         = var.project
  name            = var.url_map_name
  region          = var.lb_region
  default_service = google_compute_region_backend_service.lb-backend.self_link
}


resource "google_compute_region_backend_service" "lb-backend" {
  provider              = google-beta
  name                  = var.lb_backend_name
  region                = var.lb_region
  project               = var.project
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
  port_name             = var.lb_backend_port_name
  protocol              = var.lb_backend_protocol
  timeout_sec           = var.lb_backend_timeout
  health_checks         = [var.healthcheck_output]
  locality_lb_policy    = "ROUND_ROBIN"
  session_affinity      = "GENERATED_COOKIE"
  affinity_cookie_ttl_sec= 3600
  log_config {
    enable = true
  }

  backend {
    group           = var.ig_id
    balancing_mode  = "UTILIZATION"
    capacity_scaler = 1.0
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: 9 out of 10 a 405 is because you are doing a POST to a GET endpoint, or GET to a POST endpoint etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it configuring sticky sessions trough a cookie generated by the load balancer itself. I was trying to doing using round robin LB but it doesn't make any sense if you have to keep your session on, you must use ring hash. I'll share the script (look at the back end service):

```
  provider "google-beta" {
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
  credentials = var.credentials
}

resource "google_compute_region_ssl_certificate" "ssl-crt" {
  provider    = google-beta
  project     = var.project
  name_prefix = var.certificate_name
  region      = var.lb_region
  private_key = file("lb_http/certificate/privateKey.key")
  certificate = file("lb_http/certificate/certificate.crt")

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTP" {
  provider              = google-beta
  project               = var.project
  name                  = var.lb_http_front_name
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
  port_range            = var.lb_front_port_range
  target                = google_compute_region_target_http_proxy.lb-proxy-http.self_link
  region                = var.lb_region
  network               = var.lb_network
  subnetwork            = var.lb_subnetwork
  # ip_address            = "10.10.20.5"
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTPS" {
  provider              = google-beta
  project               = var.project
  name                  = "lb-https-front"
  port_range            = "443"
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
  # ip_address            = "10.10.20.5"
  target     = google_compute_region_target_https_proxy.lb-proxy-https.self_link
  region     = var.lb_region
  network    = var.lb_network
  subnetwork = var.lb_subnetwork
}


resource "google_compute_region_target_http_proxy" "lb-proxy-http" {
  provider = google-beta
  name     = var.lb_proxy_name
  region   = var.lb_region
  project  = var.project
  url_map  = google_compute_region_url_map.lb_url_map.self_link
}

resource "google_compute_region_target_https_proxy" "lb-proxy-https" {
  provider         = google-beta
  name             = "test-proxy"
  region           = var.lb_region
  project          = var.project
  url_map          = google_compute_region_url_map.lb_url_map.self_link
  ssl_certificates = [google_compute_region_ssl_certificate.ssl-crt.id]
}


resource "google_compute_region_url_map" "lb_url_map" {
  provider        = google-beta
  project         = var.project
  name            = var.url_map_name
  region          = var.lb_region
  default_service = google_compute_region_backend_service.lb-backend.self_link
}


resource "google_compute_region_backend_service" "lb-backend" {
  provider                        = google-beta
  name                            = var.lb_backend_name
  region                          = var.lb_region
  project                         = var.project
  load_balancing_scheme           = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
  port_name                       = var.lb_backend_port_name
  protocol                        = var.lb_backend_protocol
  timeout_sec                     = var.lb_backend_timeout
  health_checks                   = [var.healthcheck_output]
  locality_lb_policy              = "RING_HASH"
  session_affinity                = "GENERATED_COOKIE"
  affinity_cookie_ttl_sec         = 3600
  connection_draining_timeout_sec = 300
  log_config {
    enable = true
  }

  consistent_hash {
    minimum_ring_size = 3
    http_cookie {
      ttl {
        seconds = 11
        nanos   = 1111
      }
      name = "mycookie"
    }
  }

  backend {
    group           = var.ig_id
    balancing_mode  = "UTILIZATION"
    capacity_scaler = 1.0
  }
}
```